# Creating 2-dimensional vector in class C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I need to create a vector of vectors full of integers. However, I continuously get the errors:

error: expected identifier before numeric constant
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

```
using namespace std;

class Grid {
  public:

  Grid();

  void display_grid();
  void output_grid();

  private:

  vector<int> row(5, 0);
  vector<vector<int> > puzzle(9, row);
  int rows_;
  int columns_;

};
```

Comment: It would help if you had some basic knowledge of C++. For example, how to initialize class member data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize the member variables at the point where you declare them. Use an initialization list in the constructor for that:

```
Grid::Grid()
  : row(5,0), puzzle(9, row),
    rows_(5), columns_(9)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ class definitions are limited in that you cannot initialise members in-line where you declare them. It's a shame, but it's being fixed to some extent in C++0x.

Anyway, you can still provide constructor parameters with the `ctor-initializer` syntax. You may not have seen it before, but:

```
struct T {
   T() : x(42) {
      // ...
   }

   int x;
};
```

is how you initialise a member, when you might have previously tried (and failed) with `int x = 42;`.

So:

```
class Grid {
  public:

  Grid();

  void display_grid();
  void output_grid();

  private:

  vector<int> row;
  vector<vector<int> > puzzle;
  int rows_;
  int columns_;
};

Grid::Grid()
  : row(5, 0)
  , puzzle(9, row)
{
  // ...
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a member in a class declaration unless it's `const static`, because in C++ no code is being run/generated when you are declaring a class. You'll have to initialize them in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize mutable members as a part of class definition itself. Instead <s>do</s> assign it in in the constructor.

```
// ....
Grid()
{
     row.resize(5,0) ;
     puzzle.resize(9,row) ;
}
private:
   vector<int> row;
   vector<vector<int> > puzzle ;
// ..
```

Comment: @Tomalak - I am confused between the terms assignment and initialization. What is the correct terminology to use what OP is doing ? I don't think it is assignment either.

Comment: The OP is trying to do initialisation. Your code does not (though the end result is really the same, here) as you call functions on the fully-constructed objects, rather than passing constructor parameters.

Comment: @Tomalak - If my answer is confusing to say it as an initialization, I am sorry.

Comment: It's just incorrect to say. :) The approach you demonstrate is still valid, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize members in the class constructor, not the declaration. The following doesn't seem to be right in any way:

```
vector<int> row(5, 0);
vector<vector<int> > puzzle(9, row);
```

If `row` and `puzzle` are functions - the parameters should be types. If they're member variables - initialize them in the class constructor.

Comment: How are they functions? They are objects, and they are being constructed with arguments (or that was the intention).

Comment: I know that that was the intention, I'm pointing out that the syntax is wrong. Using parenthesis in definition of a class member is for functions.