# cpp initialize 2-D array using vectors compilation error

Tags: c++, vector, compilation, initialization

I'd like to initialize 2-D array m_field using initialization list in the constructor.
Like in this thread [Creating 2-dimensional vector in class C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761254/creating-2-dimensional-vector-in-class-c) , but i get errors listed below.

**BoardData.h**

```
#ifndef BOARDDATA_H
#define BOARDDATA_H

#include <vector>

class BoardData
{
    public:
    /** Default constructor */
    BoardData(int rows, int cols);
    /** Default destructor */
    virtual ~BoardData();
    protected:
    private:
    std::vector< std:vector<int> > m_field;

};


#endif // BOARDDATA_H
```

**BoardData.cpp**

```
#include "BoardData.h"

BoardData::BoardData(int rows, int cols) :
                     m_field(rows, std::vector<int>(cols,0))
{
    //ctor
}

BoardData::~BoardData()
{
    //dtor
}
```

**compiler output:** (gcc version 4.6.3)

```
BoardData.h|18|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
BoardData.h|18|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
BoardData.cpp||In constructor ‘BoardData::BoardData(int, int)’:|
BoardData.cpp|4|error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]|
BoardData.cpp|4|warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
BoardData.cpp|4|error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Hint: it's *Coordinate*, not *Coordination*, abbreviated *coord*, *coords* in plural.

Comment: Also `m_row` is completely superfluous here. Back to the book! (because that SO question was also written by a beginer. don't copy the code you don't understand).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Edited Q to my previous iteration without m_row.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "default destructor".  It's just a destructor, and you don't a comment to explain it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Documentation was generated by IDE code:blocks.

Comment: @Rob: that's no reason not to delete it!

Comment: You are missing a double column in the declaration of m_field

Comment: @JohnZwinck If i am explicitly replacing implicite dtor with my

    virtual dtor() {} 

i can call it "default destructor". But still you can write email to codeblocks devs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector< std:vector<int> > m_field;
```

should be

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > m_field;
                 ^
```

Not a very helpful error message, I agree...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fixing this compilation error, you should tweak your design.  A rectangular array should not usually be stored as a vector of vectors, but rather as a single vector which you will index in a 2D fashion.  You can use an existing library like Boost.Matrix for this, or implement it yourself:

```
m_field(rows*cols) // initialize
m_field[row + rows*col] // index
```

You can provide your own methods to index by row and column for safety.  This will in the end be more efficient than the vector-of-vectors approach.

Comment: I was not asking for optimization. I was explicitly asking why i am getting compilation error.

Comment: I don't really agree with the advice that a hacked-up 1-D array is universally "better".  If your code is simple and clear and it meets your performance requirements then that's fine.  Clarity beats unnecessary optimization, in my experience.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I mostly agree with you, but consider that a vector-of-vectors represents a jagged 2D array, not a rectangular one.  Conceptually it's cleaner to do 2D indexing into a single allocation (and the overhead is much less).